# Book where an alien asks after George Washington's descendants

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember much about the story except that there was an alien from a planet that had an aristocratic society and it was confused that George Washington's descendants weren't revered. Someone who was talking to the alien mentioned that they heard that one of his descendants got married or something. I probably read it about a decade ago but I think it came out over years before I read it.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it?  What kind of book?  Was it a novel, short story, etc?  Anything you can remember might be useful.  Please see [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the story you're looking for but I remember that there's an alien in the short story "George Washington slept here" by George L. Harness. I've forgot almost everything about the plot but it should involve building a bridge and removing the rock where this alien (who met and loved Washington) lives. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48571

Comment: @ZabZonk: https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3249382440?book_show_action=true has a few more details, but nothing that sets off bells in my head.

Comment: FYI, George Washington had no known biological children, and there is a fairly reasonable chance he was sterile.

Comment: @Buzz - Also he had wooden teeth and chased Moby Dick

Comment: @ZabZonk "George Washington Slept Here", a novella by **Charles** (not George) L. Harness, does not match the OP's description at all, but it does offer a stfnal explanation of Washington's sterility: it resulted from an encounter with a synthetic Indian woman, created millennia ago by visitors from Alpha Centauri, who happened to be radioactive. (I mean, more radioactive than a normal human being.)

Comment: @Valorum That's Captain Ahab, Dude! Wait what did he say at the hall of presidents?